# Adding leftBarButtonItem programmatically to the app

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem, appdelegate

I am trying to add leftBarButtonItem to my iPhone app. I have Navigation controller and inside it TableViewController.
I am coding the following line in my AppDelegate.m file.

```
self.viewCon = [[UITableViewController alloc]init];
    self.navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewCon];


  self.viewCon.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
initWithTitle:@"Second View"  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(push)]autorelease];
```

The navigation item does not appear on the screen. The table is on. What might be the prob?
By the way, no ARC or storyboard.

Comment: [self.navCon setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES] maybe?

Comment: What exactly did not appear? Whole navigation bar or just the button itself?

Comment: No button nor navigation bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you want a TableView with a NavigationController on top of it, in which case your root viewcontroller would be your navigation controller and not your tableview. If you built the app in IB properly (stab in the dark since I can't see what you did), then you should not have to initialize your navigation controller. If this is the case then it should be as simple as

```
self.viewCon.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Second View"  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(push)]autorelease];
```

What I think is happening is your are overwriting your currently set up NavController with your programmatic initialization which is causing everything to disappear.

If all this is the case and you may have tried this, post back the error and a screen shot of your IB setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
UIBarButtonItem *bbi = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Second View" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(push)]autorelease];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:bbi];
```

Comment: I read somewhere that it must be rootViewController. Anyway, I did as you suggested, but no affect on that.

Comment: If I add what you suggest it won't compile. If I add self.viewCon or self.navView.. it cause runt time error

Comment: In the first place as far as I know by now I need to put those lines inside ViewController.m file

Answer (score -1):

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 49,32)];
        [ backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:backButton];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = back;
        [back release];
```

Comment: What should this code solve? Do you think another bar button will work? You provided no description.

Comment: you will add this code in your view controller  and it will work

Comment: I am sure he does not want to display `UIButton` there. I am sure using `UIButton` inside `UIBarButtonItem` does not solve his problem.